# Why will my program that finds double letters not execute? Python

Tags: python, list, search

My intent is to have the program list all strings in a text file that have 3 sets of double letters. Here is the function that is supposed to return True if 3 or more double letter sets are found:

```
def three_double(s):
doubnum = 0
i=0
while i < len(s)-1:
    if s[i] == s[i+1]:
        doubnum += 1
    elif doubnum >= 3:
        return True
    else:
        i += 1
return False
```

I'm not sure why it doesn't print anything. Here is the rest of the program.

```
# Function to read and apply the three_double test to each string in
# an input file.  It counts the number of results.
def find_three_double(fin):
    count = 0
    for w in fin:
        w = w.strip()
        if three_double(w):
            print w
            count = count + 1
    if count == 0:
        print '<None found>'
    else:
        print count, 'found'

# Bring in a package to access files over the web
import urllib

# Access the file containing the valid letters
words_url = "http://thinkpython.com/code/words.txt"
words_file = urllib.urlopen(words_url)

# Apply the actual test
find_three_double(words_file)
```

Comment: The indentation is off in `three_double`. Copy/paste mistake?

Comment: @MatthewAdams, I believe that is how it is supposed to be. I didn't change that part of the program, it was part of a template I was supposed to work with

Comment: Everything under `def three_double(s):` should definitely be indented one more indent level than it is currently.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't read your code carefully at first, turns out it isn't related to `read()` or `readlines()` as you are iterating in `find_three_doubles()` function.

---

In your `three_double()` function:

```
while i < len(s)-1:
    if s[i] == s[i+1]:
        doubnum += 1
    elif doubnum >= 3:
        return True
    else:
        i += 1
return False
```

There are two problems:

- You need to increment `i` by 1 otherwise the while loop will never stop if there is a "double".
- You also need to change `elif` to `if` here because otherwise some qualified words will not be selected.

---

Fixed Code:

```
def three_double(s):
    doubnum = 0
    i=0
    while i < len(s)-1:
        if s[i] == s[i+1]:
            doubnum += 1
        if doubnum >= 3:
            return True
        i += 1
    return False


# Function to read and apply the three_double test to each string in
# an input file.  It counts the number of results.
def find_three_double(fin):
    count = 0
    for w in fin:
        w = w.strip()
        if three_double(w):
            print w
            count = count + 1
    if count == 0:
        print '<None found>'
    else:
        print count, 'found'

# Bring in a package to access files over the web
import urllib

# Access the file containing the valid letters
words_url = "http://thinkpython.com/code/words.txt"
words_file = urllib.urlopen(words_url)

# Apply the actual test
find_three_double(words_file)
```

Results:

```
aggressiveness
aggressivenesses
allottee
allottees
appellee
appellees
barrenness
barrennesses
bookkeeper
bookkeepers
bookkeeping
bookkeepings
cheerlessness
cheerlessnesses
committee
committees
greenness
greennesses
heedlessness
heedlessnesses
heelless
hyperaggressiveness
hyperaggressivenesses
keelless
keenness
keennesses
masslessness
masslessnesses
possessiveness
possessivenesses
rottenness
rottennesses
sleeplessness
stubbornness
stubbornnesses
successfully
suddenness
suddennesses
sullenness
sullennesses
toolless
wheelless
whippoorwill
whippoorwills
woodenness
woodennesses
46 found
```

Comment: hmm.. but now it reads individual letters? I need the word on each line of the file.. I tried readline() but that didn't work

Comment: @pearbear I've updated with the way you can read each line (word) into a list

Comment: @pearbear You also need to increment `i` by 1 in your `three_double()` function otherwise the while loop will never break if there is one double.

Comment: @pearbear there's probably something else that's causing the problem, I've pasted the entire code that gives the right result, check to see where you got it wrong.

Comment: Hmm, well I ended up changing the while loop to a for loop and now it works. Weird!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18440/discussion-between-pearbear-and-kay-zhu)

Answer (score 1):

[`itertools.groupby`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) can greatly simplify your program (= less bugs)

```
from itertools import groupby
import urllib

def find_three_double(words_file):
    for word in words_file:
        word = word.strip()
        if sum(sum(1 for i in g) == 2 for k,g in groupby(word)) == 3:
            print word

# Access the file containing the valid letters
words_url = "http://thinkpython.com/code/words.txt"
words_file = urllib.urlopen(words_url)

# Apply the actual test
find_three_double(words_file)
```

---

Explanation:

inside the generator expression we see `groupby(word)`. This scans the word and gathers the double letters together.

`sum(1 for i in g)` is applied to each group. It is equivalent to finding the length of the group. If the length is 2, then this is a double letter so `sum(1 for i in g) == 2` evaluates to `True`

The outer `sum()` adds up all the `True` and `False` values, `True` is added as `1` and `False` is added as `0`. If there are exactly 3 `True` values, the word is printed

Comment: +1 for groupby, but it might a bit too much for a beginner (as the OP seems to be).

Comment: @BurhanKhalid, I'm not a teacher, but I see a lot of people never seem to learn about itertools. Which is a shame really. I think implementing your own groupby (and fixing all the bugs) is a good learning exercise, but _then_ it's a good idea to learn about the one in the library.

Answer (score 0):

```
while i < len(s)-1:
    if s[i] == s[i+1]:
        doubnum += 1
    elif doubnum >= 3:
        return True
    else:
        i += 1
```

If your first check (`s[i] == s[i+1]`) is `True`, then you'll never increment `i` so the loop continues forever.

Comment: I added that but still nothing prints :(